# JAIN SIP 481 response on BYE message

Tags: java, android, sip, jain-sip

So I'm using JAIN-SIP API for call setup in some custom VOIP application of mine and I ran into an issue which is troubling me for days: I can't hang up a call with a BYE message. More precisely I keep getting 481 Call/Transaction Does Not Exist response code from callee. And I don't understand why.

Below is the stack's server log on callee side. I can provide you with source code and debug log if needed but note that source code is quite long.

```
<!-- Use the  Trace Viewer in src/tools/tracesviewer to view this  trace  
Here are the stack configuration properties 
javax.sip.IP_ADDRESS= 192.168.1.103
javax.sip.STACK_NAME= vm.nist
javax.sip.ROUTER_PATH= null
javax.sip.OUTBOUND_PROXY= null
-->
<message
from="192.168.1.103:51060" 
to="5.9.109.239:5060" 
time="1355272841980"
isSender="true" 
transactionId="z9hg4bk-cf90a986-d7f9-44a9-bd63-efb74ecc36e9" 
callId="f8270729014d0c5b17c759f60ea6510f@192.168.1.103" 
firstLine="REGISTER sip:test14.d@talk-place.com SIP/2.0" 
>
<![CDATA[REGISTER sip:test14.d@talk-place.com SIP/2.0
Call-ID: f8270729014d0c5b17c759f60ea6510f@192.168.1.103
CSeq: 366 REGISTER
From: "Test14d" <sip:test14.d@talk-place.com>;tag=18faf7d44db09f903ff5895b78787911
To: "Test14d" <sip:test14.d@talk-place.com>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 212.200.115.198:51060;rport;branch=z9hG4bK-cf90a986-d7f9-44a9-bd63-efb74ecc36e9
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: <sip:test14.d@212.200.115.198:51060;transport=udp>
Allow: INVITE,ACK,BYE,MESSAGE
User-Agent: Talk-Place
Content-Length: 0

]]>
</message>

<message
from="5.9.109.239:5060" 
to="192.168.1.103:51060" 
time="1355272842063"
isSender="false" 
transactionId="z9hg4bk-cf90a986-d7f9-44a9-bd63-efb74ecc36e9" 
callId="f8270729014d0c5b17c759f60ea6510f@192.168.1.103" 
firstLine="SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized" 
>
<![CDATA[SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Call-ID: f8270729014d0c5b17c759f60ea6510f@192.168.1.103
CSeq: 366 REGISTER
From: "Test14d" <sip:test14.d@talk-place.com>;tag=18faf7d44db09f903ff5895b78787911
To: "Test14d" <sip:test14.d@talk-place.com>;tag=b27e1a1d33761e85846fc98f5f3a7e58.6828
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.103:51060;rport=51060;branch=z9hG4bK-cf90a986-d7f9-44a9-bd63-efb74ecc36e9
WWW-Authenticate: Digest nonce="UMfTtVDH0okwmWYROC4r29415DGDKaqM",realm="talk-place.com"
Server: kamailio (3.3.2 (x86_64/linux))
Content-Length: 0

]]>
</message>

<message
from="192.168.1.103:51060" 
to="5.9.109.239:5060" 
time="1355272842069"
isSender="true" 
transactionId="z9hg4bk-cf90a986-d7f9-44a9-bd63-efb74ecc36e9" 
callId="f8270729014d0c5b17c759f60ea6510f@192.168.1.103" 
firstLine="REGISTER sip:test14.d@talk-place.com SIP/2.0" 
>
<![CDATA[REGISTER sip:test14.d@talk-place.com SIP/2.0
Call-ID: f8270729014d0c5b17c759f60ea6510f@192.168.1.103
CSeq: 367 REGISTER
From: "Test14d" <sip:test14.d@talk-place.com>;tag=18faf7d44db09f903ff5895b78787911
To: "Test14d" <sip:test14.d@talk-place.com>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 212.200.115.198:51060;rport;branch=z9hG4bK-cf90a986-d7f9-44a9-bd63-efb74ecc36e9
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: <sip:test14.d@212.200.115.198:51060;transport=udp>
Allow: INVITE,ACK,BYE,MESSAGE
User-Agent: Talk-Place
Authorization: Digest response="ec655ebc2eb8685de4fb7d739f3f0acf",username="test14.d",nonce="UMfTtVDH0okwmWYROC4r29415DGDKaqM",realm="talk-place.com",uri="sip:test14.d@talk-place.com",algorithm=MD5
Content-Length: 0

]]>
</message>

<message
from="5.9.109.239:5060" 
to="192.168.1.103:51060" 
time="1355272842118"
isSender="false" 
transactionId="z9hg4bk-cf90a986-d7f9-44a9-bd63-efb74ecc36e9" 
callId="f8270729014d0c5b17c759f60ea6510f@192.168.1.103" 
firstLine="SIP/2.0 200 OK" 
>
<![CDATA[SIP/2.0 200 OK
Call-ID: f8270729014d0c5b17c759f60ea6510f@192.168.1.103
CSeq: 367 REGISTER
From: "Test14d" <sip:test14.d@talk-place.com>;tag=18faf7d44db09f903ff5895b78787911
To: "Test14d" <sip:test14.d@talk-place.com>;tag=b27e1a1d33761e85846fc98f5f3a7e58.6828
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.103:51060;rport=51060;branch=z9hG4bK-cf90a986-d7f9-44a9-bd63-efb74ecc36e9
Contact: <sip:test14.d@192.168.1.103:51060;transport=udp>;expires=3600
Server: kamailio (3.3.2 (x86_64/linux))
Content-Length: 0

]]>
</message>

<message
from="5.9.109.239:5060" 
to="192.168.1.103:51060" 
time="1355272852008"
isSender="false" 
transactionId="z9hg4bkbd3c.62eea493.0" 
callId="2b10b9f3880ef078cb20cd9ae7075591@10.86.183.204" 
firstLine="INVITE sip:test14.d@192.168.1.103:51060;transport=udp SIP/2.0" 
>
<![CDATA[INVITE sip:test14.d@192.168.1.103:51060;transport=udp SIP/2.0
Record-Route: <sip:5.9.109.239;lr=on>
Call-ID: 2b10b9f3880ef078cb20cd9ae7075591@10.86.183.204
CSeq: 116 INVITE
From: "test14.f" <sip:test14.f@talk-place.com>;tag=32f8bc24842d02d1357bd2345c542659
To: "test14.d" <sip:test14.d@talk-place.com>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 5.9.109.239;branch=z9hG4bKbd3c.62eea493.0,SIP/2.0/UDP 77.243.22.4:36238;rport=36238;branch=z9hG4bK-f7a17df9-2242-4785-80cd-25993986008b
Max-Forwards: 69
Contact: <sip:test14.f@77.243.22.4:36238;transport=udp>
Allow: INVITE,ACK,BYE,CANCEL,OPTIONS,PRACK,REFER,NOTIFY,SUBSCRIBE,INFO,MESSAGE
User-Agent: Talk-Place
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 206

]]>
</message>

<message
from="192.168.1.103:51060" 
to="5.9.109.239:5060" 
time="1355272852027"
isSender="true" 
transactionId="z9hg4bkbd3c.62eea493.0" 
callId="2b10b9f3880ef078cb20cd9ae7075591@10.86.183.204" 
firstLine="SIP/2.0 100 Trying" 
>
<![CDATA[SIP/2.0 100 Trying
Call-ID: 2b10b9f3880ef078cb20cd9ae7075591@10.86.183.204
CSeq: 116 INVITE
From: "test14.f" <sip:test14.f@talk-place.com>;tag=32f8bc24842d02d1357bd2345c542659
To: "test14.d" <sip:test14.d@talk-place.com>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 5.9.109.239;branch=z9hG4bKbd3c.62eea493.0,SIP/2.0/UDP 77.243.22.4:36238;rport=36238;branch=z9hG4bK-f7a17df9-2242-4785-80cd-25993986008b
Content-Length: 0

]]>
</message>

<message
from="192.168.1.103:51060" 
to="5.9.109.239:5060" 
time="1355272854032"
isSender="true" 
transactionId="z9hg4bkbd3c.62eea493.0" 
callId="2b10b9f3880ef078cb20cd9ae7075591@10.86.183.204" 
firstLine="SIP/2.0 180 Ringing" 
>
<![CDATA[SIP/2.0 180 Ringing
Call-ID: 2b10b9f3880ef078cb20cd9ae7075591@10.86.183.204
CSeq: 116 INVITE
From: "test14.f" <sip:test14.f@talk-place.com>;tag=32f8bc24842d02d1357bd2345c542659
To: "test14.d" <sip:test14.d@talk-place.com>;tag=18faf7d44db09f903ff5895b78787911
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 5.9.109.239;branch=z9hG4bKbd3c.62eea493.0,SIP/2.0/UDP 77.243.22.4:36238;rport=36238;branch=z9hG4bK-f7a17df9-2242-4785-80cd-25993986008b
Contact: <sip:test14.d@212.200.115.198;transport=udp>
Content-Length: 0

]]>
</message>

<message
from="192.168.1.103:51060" 
to="5.9.109.239:5060" 
time="1355272856037"
isSender="true" 
transactionId="z9hg4bkbd3c.62eea493.0" 
callId="2b10b9f3880ef078cb20cd9ae7075591@10.86.183.204" 
firstLine="SIP/2.0 200 OK" 
>
<![CDATA[SIP/2.0 200 OK
Record-Route: <sip:5.9.109.239;lr=on>
Call-ID: 2b10b9f3880ef078cb20cd9ae7075591@10.86.183.204
CSeq: 116 INVITE
From: "test14.f" <sip:test14.f@talk-place.com>;tag=32f8bc24842d02d1357bd2345c542659
To: "test14.d" <sip:test14.d@talk-place.com>;tag=18faf7d44db09f903ff5895b78787911
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 5.9.109.239;branch=z9hG4bKbd3c.62eea493.0,SIP/2.0/UDP 77.243.22.4:36238;rport=36238;branch=z9hG4bK-f7a17df9-2242-4785-80cd-25993986008b
Contact: <sip:test14.d@212.200.115.198;transport=udp>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 218

]]>
</message>

<message
from="5.9.109.239:5060" 
to="192.168.1.103:51060" 
time="1355272856327"
isSender="false" 
transactionId="z9hg4bkcydzigwkx" 
callId="2b10b9f3880ef078cb20cd9ae7075591@10.86.183.204" 
firstLine="ACK sip:test14.d@192.168.1.103:51060;transport=udp SIP/2.0" 
>
<![CDATA[ACK sip:test14.d@192.168.1.103:51060;transport=udp SIP/2.0
Call-ID: 2b10b9f3880ef078cb20cd9ae7075591@10.86.183.204
CSeq: 117 ACK
From: "test14.f" <sip:test14.f@talk-place.com>;tag=32f8bc24842d02d1357bd2345c542659
To: "test14.d" <sip:test14.d@talk-place.com>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 5.9.109.239;branch=z9hG4bKcydzigwkX,SIP/2.0/UDP 77.243.22.4:36238;rport=36238;branch=z9hG4bK-f7a17df9-2242-4785-80cd-25993986008b
Max-Forwards: 69
Allow: INVITE,ACK,BYE,CANCEL,OPTIONS,PRACK,REFER,NOTIFY,SUBSCRIBE,INFO,MESSAGE
User-Agent: Talk-Place
Content-Length: 0

]]>
</message>

<message
from="192.168.1.103:51060" 
to="5.9.109.239:5060" 
time="1355272856339"
isSender="true" 
transactionId="z9hg4bkcydzigwkx" 
callId="2b10b9f3880ef078cb20cd9ae7075591@10.86.183.204" 
firstLine="SIP/2.0 200 OK" 
>
<![CDATA[SIP/2.0 200 OK
Call-ID: 2b10b9f3880ef078cb20cd9ae7075591@10.86.183.204
CSeq: 117 ACK
From: "test14.f" <sip:test14.f@talk-place.com>;tag=32f8bc24842d02d1357bd2345c542659
To: "test14.d" <sip:test14.d@talk-place.com>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 5.9.109.239;branch=z9hG4bKcydzigwkX,SIP/2.0/UDP 77.243.22.4:36238;rport=36238;branch=z9hG4bK-f7a17df9-2242-4785-80cd-25993986008b
Content-Length: 0

]]>
</message>

<message
from="5.9.109.239:5060" 
to="192.168.1.103:51060" 
time="1355272856728"
isSender="false" 
transactionId="z9hg4bk9e3c.74261c85.0" 
callId="2b10b9f3880ef078cb20cd9ae7075591@10.86.183.204" 
firstLine="BYE sip:test14.d@192.168.1.103:51060;transport=udp SIP/2.0" 
>
<![CDATA[BYE sip:test14.d@192.168.1.103:51060;transport=udp SIP/2.0
Call-ID: 2b10b9f3880ef078cb20cd9ae7075591@10.86.183.204
CSeq: 119 BYE
From: "test14.f" <sip:test14.f@talk-place.com>;tag=32f8bc24842d02d1357bd2345c542659
To: "test14.d" <sip:test14.d@talk-place.com>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 5.9.109.239;branch=z9hG4bK9e3c.74261c85.0,SIP/2.0/UDP 77.243.22.4:36238;rport=36238;branch=z9hG4bK-f7a17df9-2242-4785-80cd-25993986008b
Max-Forwards: 69
Allow: INVITE,ACK,BYE,CANCEL,OPTIONS,PRACK,REFER,NOTIFY,SUBSCRIBE,INFO,MESSAGE
User-Agent: Talk-Place
Content-Length: 0

]]>
</message>

<message
from="192.168.1.103:51060" 
to="5.9.109.239:5060" 
time="1355272856738"
isSender="true" 
transactionId="z9hg4bk9e3c.74261c85.0" 
callId="2b10b9f3880ef078cb20cd9ae7075591@10.86.183.204" 
firstLine="SIP/2.0 481 Call leg/Transaction does not exist" 
>
<![CDATA[SIP/2.0 481 Call leg/Transaction does not exist
Call-ID: 2b10b9f3880ef078cb20cd9ae7075591@10.86.183.204
CSeq: 119 BYE
From: "test14.f" <sip:test14.f@talk-place.com>;tag=32f8bc24842d02d1357bd2345c542659
To: "test14.d" <sip:test14.d@talk-place.com>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 5.9.109.239;branch=z9hG4bK9e3c.74261c85.0,SIP/2.0/UDP 77.243.22.4:36238;rport=36238;branch=z9hG4bK-f7a17df9-2242-4785-80cd-25993986008b
Server: vm.nist
Content-Length: 0

]]>
</message>
```

Answer (score 1):

The UAS rejects the `BYE` request because it does not contain the `tag` in the `To` header.  The `ACK` request should also have the `tag`.  How are you creating these requests?

Comment: Hi @yoyommy,

I'm creating those requests with MessageFactory.createRequest(); method. I should have mentioned the following in my question: I'm removing tags from ACK and BYE requests To headers explicitly because if I don't ACK requests never reach the callee and server sends 404 responses to BYE requests.

Thanks,
Milan

Comment: Additionally, for testing purposes I used to make calls from an Android client to a Java(desktop) client and BYE never worked(as described in my question). However, last night I've tried making a call from one Android client to another Android client and it worked. Which is very strange because desktop client and Android client share the SIP-related code. Basically the only difference is that on Android  I had to rename JAIN-SIP packages from javax.sip and gov.nist to javaxvm.sip and vm.nist respectively due to Android having a hidden JAIN-SIP API.

Comment: The From tag, To tag and Call-ID uniquely identify the call leg, so you will _always_ get a `481 Call Leg/Transaction Does Not Exist` if you remove the To tag!

Comment: According to RFC 3261, the To tag **must** be present for all subsequent requests (incluing ACK and BYE).  Try creating these requests using `SIPDialog.createAck()` and `SIPDialog.createRequest("BYE")` instead of `MessageFactory`.

Comment: Thanks guys,
Creating messages with SIPDialog methods doesn't work either. At least not on the desktop test client.
But what matters is that somehow I fixed the Android client, which was my primary objective. BYE now works even without the To header tag. If I manage to figure out what was wrong I'll post the explanation here.